# JPA error : without eclipselink

Tags: java, servlets, jpa

I am developing a proof of concept wherein I am creating JPA entities in Dynamic web project and using a servlet to retrieve information.
I am deploying this application in SAP NW Java AS.
Please ignore the name odata in below code snippets as it has nothing to do with odata.

I am getting below error :

> WebServletException: Web container failed to find a resource needed
> for injection, the following class [com.EXIDVPServFactory] cannot be
> put into service.
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The persistence unit is inconsistent with the database schema:
> Error on entity >>model.ZaeExidvp<<: The table >>ZAE_EXIDVP<< does not exist.**

My persistence.xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="XXXXXXX" xmlns:xsi="XXXXXX" xsi:schemaLocation="XXXXXXXX http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="basicodata" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>javax.persistence.PersistenceProvider</provider>
  <class>model.ZaeExidvp</class>
  <class>model.ZaeExidvpPK</class>
 
  <properties>
                     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
                     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sapsr3db"/>
                     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="XXXXXX"/>
                     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
              </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The servlet that I am using is :

```
package com;
 
 
import java.io.IOException;
import model.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.persistence.*;
 
 
 
 
/**
* Servlet implementation class EXIDVPServFactory
*/
public class EXIDVPServFactory extends HttpServlet {
  //@PersistenceUnit (unitName = "basicodata")
  private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "basicodata";
  
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public EXIDVPServFactory() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
 
 
  /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  //EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  // ODataJPAContext oDatJPAContext = this.getODataJPAContext();
  String aufnr = request.getParameter("aufnr");
  ZaeExidvp exidvp = em.find(ZaeExidvp.class, aufnr);
  response.getOutputStream().print(exidvp.getId().toString());
 
  }
 
 
  /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
 
 
}
```

CLASS ZAE_EXIDVP (Entity object)

```
package model;
 
 
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
 
 
 
 
/**
* The persistent class for the ZAE_EXIDVP database table.
*
*/
@Entity
@Table(name="ZAE_EXIDVP")
public class ZaeExidvp implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 
  @EmbeddedId
  private ZaeExidvpPK id;
 
 
 
 
 
    public ZaeExidvp() {
    }
 
 
  public ZaeExidvpPK getId() {
  return this.id;
  }
 
 
  public void setId(ZaeExidvpPK id) {
  this.id = id;
  }
 
 
 
 
 
}
```

I have created a simple HTML page that will send one aufnr id as parameter to servlet.
Please assist me in resolving this.

Comment: do you have the table with specified name in database?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar He doesn't need to, please see my answer, JPA can be configured to create tables automatically. Lord knows why this isn't the default configuration.

Comment: @hd1 I know it can be done Upvote from me. But it is always good to know what exactly is going on in the backend :) and what if later he does not want to delete the tables next time he restarts server?

Comment: Then OP can change the value to [one of the other valid ones](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines to your persistence.xml:

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>
```

Hope that helps. The other options for eclipse.ddl-generation may be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_ddl_generation.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My  table already exist in database. My objetive is to only fetch information from that table using JPA layer.

Comment: Also I dont want to use eclipselink, as it is giving me some wierd error which will be fixed only once my SAP java sever is upgraded

Comment: What's the "weird error"? IME, Java tools are very robust, but difficult to configure properly. Edit your question with a stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may also occur if your table `ZAE_EXIDVP` exist in the database and if the table you created in database may be not visible to the user, which is used to connect to DB.

Comment: In my persistance.xml I have hardcoded userid and password...these are exactly same that i use to login...Infact i have tried similar persistence.xml in tomcat server... Here in this scenario server is SAP